# Make a list of just a few links

Tags: netlogo

I have a complete directed weighted graph and with this line of code:

```
ask turtles
[
   show max-one-of my-in-links [trust]
]
```

I've managed to get back the links with maximum weight (or trust) per each turtle.
the problem I'm having is entering each of these links in a list because for this line of code

```
foreach sort-on [(- label)] links
```

I want **links** to refer only to the few links with maximum value per each turtle.
In other words I want to know what to write instead of links.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this, but you can try something like:

```
let test-links [max-one-of my-in-links [trust]] of turtles
```

That is, you use exactly the same construction as the `ask` with an `of` instead. Alternatively, you can use the `ask` to iteratively construct the list, with something like (verbose version so you can see what it's doing):

```
let test-links []
ask turtles
[
   let this-link max-one-of my-in-links [trust]
   set test-links lput this-link test-links
]
```